# boolean値である変数の Trueのみ含むnumpy配列 の出力

Tags: python, numpy

変数 a は boolean です。
この a から True のみを出力する際のコマンドは、以下で良いのでしょうか？

```
print(np.where(a == True))
```

以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。レベルの低い質問で申し訳ありませんが何方か教えてください。

```
(array([0, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False])
>>> a
array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False])
>>> a[a]
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```

> 以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

それはエラーではなく、インデックス番号です。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございました!  print(aの元となる連続変数[a]) で解決しました! 手数お掛けしました。